# IF, OR, LEFT, RIGHT functions together in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm fairly new to VBA. I have this excel formula to update attendance based on the date, work week. which is working fine in excel. but I am not able to integrate it to vba

this is my excel formula for column I

```
=IF(OR(H2=LEFT(F2,3),H2=RIGHT(F2,3)),"O","W")
```

[image]

This is the VBA CODE

```
Sub Attendance()
Dim dsh As Worksheet
Set dsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATABASE")

With dsh
   If dsh.Range("H").Value = Left(dsh.Range("F").Value, 3) Or dsh.Range("H").Value = Right(dsh.Range("F").Value, 3) Then
       dsh.Range("I").Value = "O"
   Else
       dsh.Range("I").Value = "W"
   End If
End With

End Sub
```

I'm getting this error when I try to run it -

> method 'range' of object '_worksheet' failed.

Comment: `"H"` is not a valid `Range` reference. `"H2"` is. You need to refer to a single cell here, which means that ... (see the next comment)

Comment: You will need to loop the range.

Comment: Though you could use VBA to just write the formula directly to the cells in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Attendance()
For I = 2 To Range("E999").End(3).Row
    If Left(Cells(I, 6), 3) = Cells(I, 8) Or Right(Cells(I, 6), 3) = Cells(I, 8) Then
        Cells(I, 9) = "O"
    Else
        Cells(I, 9) = "W"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @Can.U, this was very helpful. Thank you BigBen, Scott Craner. very much appreciated your advice.